# Gerar uma chave aleatória em um Charfield Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Estou criando uma API cadastro com três campos em Django ('login', 'senha', 'data de nascimento')

Porém no campo senha eu tenho que deixar como opcional, e caso o usuário não digite uma senha, peço para que o *random* me gere uma senha aleatória e armazene ela no banco.

```
senha  = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

Minha dúvida é em criar uma condição ***if*** falando que caso esse campo fique vazio gerar um *random* pra mim que será armazenado no BD

```
if senha == '':
    abc = string.ascii_letters
    pontuacao = string.punctuation
    senha = abc + pontuacao
    ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choices(senha, k=15))
```

Comment: Essa resposta não é específica pra Django mas você pode utilizar as ideias presentes lá para implementar esta lógica de gerar valores aleatórios.

Comment: Sua model de usuário está herdando o AbstractUser?